# Python - Spatial variance of a parameter in a netCDF file

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a netCDF file `monthly_qc_data.nc`, representing the monthly value of a parameter call `Lai_500m` in a bounding box of 0.5º.

Considering that the center of the bounding box/netCDF file is the reference point. I would like to calculate the difference of the parameter `Lai_500m` against the value of this parameter on the center of the bounding box.

For that I am using the following:

```
##SPATIAL VARIANCE
os.chdir(inbasedir)
data = xr.open_dataset('monthly_qc_data.nc')
ref_data = data.where((data['lat'] ==  10) & (data['lon'] == 10)) #considering the poin lat:10 and lon:10 as the center of the bounding box
dif_data = data.where((data['Lai_500m'] - ref_data))
```

Unfortunately this returns the following error:

```
ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be 
safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I also tried using python netCDF4:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset 
os.chdir(inbasedir)
dataset = Dataset("monthly_qc_data.nc")
dif_data = dataset.variables['Lai_500m'][:,:,:] - dataset.variables['Lai_500m'][:,10,10]
```

who also returned the (obvious) error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (12,120,120) (12,)
```

Does anyone knows how to overcome that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get your ref_data as a float and then subtract from the dataset, i.e.

```
ref_data = float(data.Lai_500m.sel(lat=10.0, lon=10.0).values)
dif_data = data.Lai_500m - ref_data
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you were looking for a python answer, but just in case it is useful, here is how you could do the same function from the command line with cdo:

```
cdo sub in.nc -remapnn,lon=10/lat=10 in.nc diff.nc
```